# AWS DMS ERROR : Last Error Load utility network error. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am trying to replicate data from RDS (POSTGRES 9.6) to REDSHIFT using Data Migration Service of AWS.

I have configured RDS in CDC mode and ran DMS job with Full Load + CDC option.
Using Replication Config : dms.c5.4xlarge (32GB) .

After successfully running FULL LOAD + CDC suddenly the job failed with the following error message :

**`Last Error Load utility network error. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2860] [1020458] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_JJ6J5HNCIGLCUMQJNNBGWCGA2YHJU2CQI6QJG6Y; Stream component 'st_0_JJ6J5HNCIGLCUMQJNNBGWCGA2YHJU2CQI6QJG6Y' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2868] [1020458] Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE`**

What could be the possible cause of this scenario? I checked the NETWORK THROUGHPUT as well and everything seems to be in good shape.

TIA

Comment: Facing this same issue.
any help?